# Can not return ActionResult from method when using Uploadify MVC3 application

Tags: jquery, debugging, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

If I use this as my Controller Action...FAIL.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
    {
        var saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("\\"),"returns");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
        FileData.SaveAs(Path.Combine(saveLocation, FileData.FileName));
        ViewBag.Message = String.Format("File name: {0}, {1}Kb Uploaded Successfully.", FileData.FileName, (int)FileData.ContentLength / 1024); 
        return View();
    }
```

When I run my web app and try to upload a file I get a progress bar that works, gets to a random percentage, then returns a generic error.

[image]

## However!!

This Controller Action works perfect.

```
         [HttpPost]
         public String Upload(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
         {
             var saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("\\"),"returns");
             System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
             FileData.SaveAs(Path.Combine(saveLocation,FileData.FileName));
             ViewBag.Message = String.Format("File name: {0}, {1}Kb Uploaded Successfully.", FileData.FileName, (int)FileData.ContentLength / 1024);
             return ViewBag.Message; 
         }
```

---

**Here is the code from my upload page.  All the script references are loaded in site.master.**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>



<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewBag.Message %></h2>
    <%= this.Profile.TaxPayerID  %>
    <p>Please upload your return</p>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
            'uploader': '/Scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': '/Images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Select DR405',
            'script': 'Home/Upload',
            'folder': '/returns',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.csv;*.txt;*.xls;*.xlsx',
            'auto': true
        });
    }
);
    </script>

<div id="fileuploader"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Why can't I return ActionResult?

Comment: Sorry I don't see a difference between the controller action that you marked as the one that works, and the one you marked as the one that does not work.

Comment: @Jay - Fighting with SO's formatting I inadvertently pasted the same one twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticing a few things here. Not sure why your MVC3 app has asp tags and a page declaration header. The uploadify requires an input tage type="file" with a unique ID on the page, but your example points to a div tag. Try changing that to a `<input type="file"/>` tag.

Comment: I didn't opt to use Razor view engine. Please note, that in my question I indicate the they application works fine. I would like to know __WHY__ returning `ActionResult` instead of `String` causes the failure. I would like to learn more, not have a problem fixed.

Comment: The only guess I have as to why it isn't working is the shockwave applet is expecting a certain content type back. By sending a string back the mime type will be 'text/plain' where as a view will be 'text/html'.

Answer (score 0):

The typical upload handler (`ashx` version) for uploadify does something like this:

```
//  if the file was saved successfully...
{
    context.Response.Write("1");
}
else
{
    // Let client know about failure
    context.Response.Write("0");
}
```

That means that the client uploader is expecting a response that is either a simple 1 or 0 text string to say if it succeeded. That is probably the simplest return they could work with.

The equivalent in MVC is to return a string "0" or "1" in response to a successful save. That means you need a simple return type of `string`. If you return a 'View()' as an `ActionResult` the client uploader gets back an entire HTML page from the server and does not know what to do with it (hence the error).

If you view the working and non-working version in Fiddler2 (highly recommended) you would have seen the difference instantly.